# Ebay API Version overriding?

Tags: ebay-api

Even though I'm setting Compavility version in request header (967), when I'm making a call (GeteBayDetails in that case), the response comes with version higher than I need and want (979). These applies to both app I'm currently developing and even API Test Tool. Is there something that I'm missing? Or the Version tag in response isn't related to Compability Level?

Header:

```
X-EBAY-API-SITEID:212
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:967
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GeteBayDetails
```

Body:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <GeteBayDetailsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
     <RequesterCredentials>
       <eBayAuthToken>...</eBayAuthToken>
     </RequesterCredentials>
   </GeteBayDetailsRequest>
```

And the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeteBayDetailsResponse 
  xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2016-09-27T11:21:41.341Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Nieznany błąd.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Nieznany błąd.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>17460</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Version>979</Version>
  <Build>E979_INTL_API_18061441_R1</Build>
</GeteBayDetailsResponse>
```

PS. As far as I know, request fails because of the newer version of the API. And worked before like a charm. Thats why I want to stick to 967.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is normal behavior in that the response will always contain the most recent API schema that could service your request.  I encounter many calls for which there are no applicable *execution* differences between the requested schema and the performing schema, for a given particular request.  Also this returning "latest schema version that could service the API request" behavior is how you can determine if you can move up your compatibility level safely, as support drops off periodically.

Of course when the response has a lower schema than the latest in the release notes for the API, then you know you are in a situation where at some point you have to change your code to reflect what has been deprecated or changed before the support for the last schema that can service your particular request ends.

This eBay DTS article mentions this [Information in the API Response](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=389)
as well as going over the eBay API schema versioning process.

Also, be sure on XML POST requests to specify the API schema version in the request itself using the *Version* tag, not just the HTTP header as with the example call code for the GeteBayDetails API documentation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayDetailsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
  <DetailName> DetailNameCodeType </DetailName>
  <!-- ... more DetailName values allowed here ... -->
  <!-- Standard Input Fields -->
  <ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
  <MessageID> string </MessageID>
  <Version> string </Version>
  <WarningLevel> WarningLevelCodeType </WarningLevel>
</GeteBayDetailsRequest>
```

Hope this helps